# Rear USB ports on my NUC pc are not working

Tags: windows-8, usb, windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

I recently bought [this Intel NUC PC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SD9IS1S) to use as a media PC connected to my TV. I installed Windows 10 on it and it was working fine for a while. Then the rear USB ports stopped working. I was fooling around with an XInput Wrapper for my PS3 controller, specifically [this one](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwizueuTqafKAhWCNT4KHchlDQcQFgg4MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.pcsx2.net%2FThread-XInput-Wrapper-for-DS3-and-Play-com-USB-Dual-DS2-Controller&usg=AFQjCNFiIzkRKbTnIp2VA8EJisHynoL78w&sig2=QxIHWb4vZusr4UIcPjrZ-Q) and [this one](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiGjsHEqafKAhXIaz4KHUUnCLgQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.pcsx2.net%2FThread-ScpToolkit-XInput-Wrapper-aka-ScpServer-Reloaded&usg=AFQjCNGXMYWapJa08wa3CqYdOw8pvUiuKw&sig2=fXSLy6vfJ9WR-2ooMwVUeQ&bvm=bv.111396085,d.cWw). These programs overwrite a lot of USB drivers for Bluetooth functionality and such. I've used these tools in the past on other PCs with little issue.

Anyways, the rear USB ports stopped working and I thought it might have something to do with the DS3 tools (I was doing a lot of wiping of drivers and reinstalling because my controllers had stopped working). I kinda wanted to go back to Windows 8 anyways, so I reformatted the computer. I installed Windows 8.1 and went through all my windows update (I did not install an DS3 tool yet), and my USB ports are still not working.

Any ideas what might be wrong? How can I begin to troublshoot this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look in the bios for any usb settings?

Comment: Unless you can (and have) disabled the USB ports via a BIOS option, the odds are the ports have physically failed.

Comment: Excellent suggestion @maob. ;)

Comment: Ok, I'll check out the BIOS when I get home from work. Though I don't see why anything there would have changed. I even flashed a new BIOS update as part of the initial driver install when I put Windows 8 on it. But it certainly wouldn't hurt to look.

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes Windows won't pick up on a driver need. Did you go to the Intel site and grab drivers from them? On some of my new builds, stuff won't be detected by windows until I install drivers (from Mobo dvd, or vendor site). From that point forward, Windows seems to see it and push in driver updates after that.

Comment: @CarlB Yes, I installed all the drivers from Intel's page for my model of NUC

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yeah, guess the hardware was just defective. All usb ports were set to "enabled" in the BIOS

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is a hardware issue. Must be defective.... Luckily Amazon accepted a return no problem.